# get the count value for this week

Tags: mysql, count

i have to use below query for get the count value on today.

```
select *
from orders 
where status='P' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date),'%Y-%m-%d')=CURDATE();
```

it is successfully displayed count value.but get the count value for this month means have to use this below query.

```
select * from xcart_orders where status='C' AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date),'%m')=DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m');
```

it is successfully displayed correct count value.

How is get the count value for this week..please help me.how is write the query for this week

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MS SQL? MySql?

Comment: Looks like mysql judging by the function names

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove:

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date),'%Y-%m-%d')= (MONTH(date)
```

your query should be:

```
select * 
from orders 
where status='P' AND 
(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND 
(YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE());
```

Comment: ya this comment is worked on date field is saved in date format.but my field is saved in timestamp format on my database

Comment: @krishnaveni, you may use `FROM_UNIXTIME` to get the date and then use MONTH method to get the month and compare it with the current month, check the updated query

Comment: @krishnaveni, you may trin remove the `status = 'p'` check, may be status field for your records of the same month contains something other than 'p`

Comment: i got the output for this month

Comment: @krishnaveni, what did you do ?

Comment: use below query for get the count value for this month:select * from xcart_orders where status='C' AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date),'%m')=DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m');

Comment: but i have one doubts.how is get the count value for this week...what query i have to write.please help me

Answer (score 0):

Just modifying your query a little, this should work:

```
select * from orders 
where status='P'
AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE());
```

You could rewrite this as:

```
select * from orders 
where status='P'
AND EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW())
```

Comment: ya it is worked on date field is saved in date format.but my field is saved in timestamp format

Comment: shouldn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me, try it and let me know

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_field), '%u')=date_format(now(), '%u')
```